# compare decimal values in varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqldatatypes

I have a `varchar` column by name XYZ and the values in that column are like

```
XYZ
10.2
9.0
97.32
```

When I write a case statement something like

```
CASE 
    WHEN XYZ > '9.0' THEN
    'DONE'
    WHEN XYZ < '7.0' THEN
    'NOT DONE'
    WHEN XYZ BETWEEN '7.0' AND '9.0' THEN
    'NULL'
     END
```

It is not comparing with the values. What should be done to fix this?

Comment: "What should be done to fix this"? Store numeric values using a numeric datatype. Any reason for using `varchar`? Can this be changed? If not do you have any non numeric values in the column?

Comment: the coloumn datatype is in varchar.The coloumn does not have any non numeric values.

Comment: I know it's `varchar` you say that in the question. You also ask what **should** be done to fix it. Answer. Use a more appropriate datatype.

Comment: so you mean to say cast that coloumn with a decimal datatype?

Comment: No I mean change the schema of the table itself (i.e. datatype of the column). This is more efficient storage wise, will prevent non numeric data entering the table and be correct semantically thus avoiding the need for casts every time you want to do numeric comparisons and sorting.

Comment: I understand that, that is how it should be done but the company uses a third party front end application from where the data comes in. I belive its not possible to change the schema to the table as well. This can be done with the dev database but surely not with prod server. In that case by code will fail against the prod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to determine whether the data is numeric before doing the cast. Denali has a `TRY_CONVERT` function but in previous versions you need to use a `CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(XYZ + 'e0') = 1` statement which could either be incorporated into the main `CASE` or separated out as below

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE
(
XYZ VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @YourTable
SELECT 'foo' AS XYZ
UNION ALL 
SELECT '8.9'
UNION ALL 
SELECT '9.1'
UNION ALL 
SELECT '6.5'

SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN _XYZ > 9 THEN
    'DONE'
    WHEN _XYZ < 7 THEN
    'NOT DONE'
     END
FROM @YourTable
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(XYZ + 'e0') = 1 
            THEN CAST(XYZ AS NUMERIC(18,8)) END) CA(_XYZ)
```

Answer (score 2):

if you know the data is clean, you can run a cast (or convert) statement on the field.

`CASE
    WHEN CAST(XYZ AS decimal) > 9.0 THEN 'DONE'
    WHEN CAST(XYZ AS decimal) < 7.0 THEN 'NOT DONE'
    WHEN CAST(XYZ AS decimal) BETWEEN 7.0 AND 9.0 THEN 'NULL'
END`

Note that you should lose the quotes around the '9.0' 
Also of note, the cast operation is going to be run against the entire field.  This will make the use of indexes useless as it has to scan the entire table to make the conversion before it can make the comparison.  This can have serious performance implications for even moderately large tables (ie 10-100k records).

Comment: yes, This was the first thing which striked into my mind.While trying to do that my package is taking long time to run. So i guess this will not workout as well in my case.

Answer (score 2):

If the column indeed represents only numbers and is never expected to contain anything else but numbers, then just do a one-time operation of converting the column to a more appropriate type. Depending on the nature of the data, you might have to choose between precise and approximate types, namely, `decimal` and `float`/`real`. For the former you'd also have to choose the right precision and scale (the number of digits after the decimal point).

The conversion itself would look basically like this:

```
ALTER TABLE atable
ALTER COLUMN XYZ decimal(15, 2)
```

Again, you will need to make sure there are no non-number values in the column, otherwise the statement is going to fail.

Comment: I do not have the permissions to run an alter statement. And i could also find some other data present in that coloumn. So the cast statement also fails to cast it with other datatype such as decimal,float,real

Answer (score 0):

```
WHEN ISNUMERIC(XYZ) = 0 
                                THEN 'DONE'
                WHEN CONVERT(DECIMAL,XYZ) > 9 
                                THEN 'NOT DONE'
                WHEN CONVERT(DECIMAL,XYZ) < 7.0 
                                THEN 'SOMETIMES DONE'
                WHEN CONVERT(DECIMAL,XYZ) BETWEEN 7.0 AND 9.0 
                                THEN 'EVERYTIME DONE'
                WHEN ISNULL(XYZ,'') = '' 
                                THEN 'NONE'
END
```

yahoo atlast done! This worked out for me.
Thanks for your help and useful advice 
Appretiate all your time.